# Calculating rates / 'derivative' with awk

Tags: text-processing, awk, gawk, numeric-data

`awk` newbie here.

Suppose I have two columns of data, and I want to calculate the rate of increase, given by delta(y)/delta(x). How would I do this in an `awk` script? What I've learnt so far only deals with line by line manipulation, and I'm not sure how I'd work with multiple lines.

Note: Suppose I have N data points, I would get N-1 values of the slope/rate.

Example:

- Input

  ```
  x y 
  2 4 
  3 5 
  4 7
  ```
- Output

  ```
  Slope
  -
  1
  2
  ```

Is `awk` the best option here? or is some other tool better?

Comment: For such questions you should always give example input and output.

Comment: @HaukeLaging I hope it's clearer now

Comment: I think this is your output file and the input is just the first 2 columns? As a rule you should post the input and output separately and the code you have tried with any errors or the "wrong output" somewhere in the middle. The we can help you correct or develop you approach.

Comment: What output are you expecting from that input? Or is that the output? If so, what was the input? Please [edit] your question and show us i) your input file and ii) the output you want from that file. It's very hard to undertsand what you need otherwise.

Comment: My apologies, that was just the concept of the rate made concrete with an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use variables to store data that you need to remember from one line to the next.

Line N+1 in the output is calculated from lines N and N+1 in the input, so you need variables to store the content of the previous line. There are two fields per line, so use one variable for each.

Lines 1 and 2 get special treatment (title line, and not enough data). You can match specific line numbers by testing the special variable `NR`. The instruction `next` causes the rest of the processing to be skipped for the current line.

Since this processing is fairly simple, it's enough to use variables for the content of the previous line. Once you've processed the current line, using the variables that were set when processing the previous line, store the contents of the current line into the variables.

```c
NR == 1 { print "Slope"; next; }
NR == 2 { print "-"; }
NR >= 3 { print ($2 - y) / ($1 - x) }
NR >= 2 { x = $1; y = $2; }
```

Recall that awk runs the code for each input line in turn, and the expression before each braced group is a condition for running this group, so this is equivalent to the following pseudocode:

```
for each line {
    NR = current line number;
    $1 = first field; $2 = second field;
    if (NR == 1) { print "Slope"; next; }
    …
}
```

Alternatively, you might find the code more readable if you give names both to the previous line's data and to the current line's data. At the end of the current line processing, transfer the data from the “current” variables to the “previous” variables.

```c
NR == 1 { print "Slope"; next; }
NR == 2 { print "-"; }
NR >= 2 { current_x = $1; current_y = $2; }
NR >= 3 { print (current_y - previous_y) / (current_x - previous_x) }
NR >= 2 { previous_x = current_x; previous_y = current_y; }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$ awk 'NR==1 { print; next; }; '\
'      NR==2 { former_x=$1; former_y=$2; $3="-"; print; next; };'\
' { $3=($2-former_y)/($1-former_x); print; former_x=$1; former_y=$2; }' input

x y Slope
2 4 -
3 5 1
4 7 2
```

The first line is just printed as is.

In all the following lines you have to store the values from columns `x` and `y` so that they can be used for the calculation in the following line. Line 2 is handled specially because there is nothing to compute yet.

In all the following lines the ratio is computed, added as a new field to the line, the line is printed, and the values from that line are stored.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your input is

```
x y
2 4
3 5
4 7
4 8
```

Then

```
awk 'NR==1{print $0" Slope"; getline}
  {dx=($1-xold); dy=($2-yold);$3=(xold&&dx!=0)?dy/dx:"-"; xold=$1; yold=$2; print}' file
```

Gives you

```
x y Slope
2 4 -
3 5 1
4 7 2
4 8 -
```

**Explanation-o**

```
awk 'NR==1{print $0" Slope"; getline}
```

If it is the first record / line `NR==1` then print it along with the additional title and jump to the next line `getline`

```
  {dx=($1-xold); dy=($2-yold);
```

Calculate `dx` and `dy`

```
  $3=(xold&&dx!=0)?dy/dx:"-";
```

If `xold` has been initalised (which only happens on line 2 after this test and so this only fails on line 2) and `dx!=0` (there is no div 0 error) then `$3=dy/dx` otherwise `$3="-"`

```
     xold=$1; yold=$2;
```

Then update `xold` and `yold` values to the current x and y on this record / line

```
      print}' file
```

And then print the whole record / line (including the new `$3`)

Comment: @ilkkachu What's up with Same-o and Explanation-o? I don't follow XD

Comment: @SuraajKS, I just meant that the two answers were originally quite brief, and seemed like they wouldn't be very easy to follow for someone who isn't that familiar with awk. "Same-o" was just lazy writing.